# Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes)?

Tags: php

I am getting this error. I have increased the memory limit upto 512M. I have more than 4000 posts with so many data. Website is working fine. But when I am trying to access the custom post type page in admin section to see posts of that custom type this shows the error. I have read this blog also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486365/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allo).

I think the problem is with the php script on edit page template. `select * from table where ....`. How can I edit this custom post type template page to limit the number of posts in admin section on custom post type. I think this is somewhere in wp-admin folder.

Or there is something else I  misunderstood about the infinite loop.

Please suggest me . Increasing the memory limit in config.php is not working for me.

Comment: Maybe you're viewing all the posts at once?  What's the number of posts in your screen options?

Comment: How many posts are you trying to show on each page, and what custom columns are present?

Comment: This number was 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the max memory limit.

I had defined in config.php define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M'); But this was not working for me. But then I see , I need to define this  define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );  also in config.php.  Now custom property type is working for me. Now I can edit this post type.

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate implementation detail of post queries in WP is that they will drag all of post data into memory. It is hard to say if this is definitely the reason in your case, but it might be. Although posts per page is capped at maximum of 999 in admin and it should handle that many normal posts with sufficient memory.

The amount per page is stored as `edit_{$post_type}_per_page` in user meta.

You can check and modify it with WP-CLI

```
C:\server\www\dev>wp user meta get 1 edit_post_per_page
999
```

Or in `wp_usermeta` database table.

Comment: I hoped your answer will help me. But edit_property_per_page is 200. Now this has increased my tension, How could I find the solution. So far thanks for your attention.

Comment: The problem is still there..can there not be any other issue? Please

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few reasons for this. The first is it's literally that the data you're requesting is maxing out. If that's the case use LIMIT to reduce the number of records returned.

Select * from table limit 10.

Returns 10 records.

Other more trickier reasons could be a plugin has gone slightly rogue or you've altered a script somewhere else that is causing an infinite loop or huge join to occur.

You should try and investigate the error logs.